# ASP.NET how to disable button on submit?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, javascript

I have forms with payment in ASP.NET site, when user clicks on asp:Button sometime he submits few times. I want to disable this functionality without harming current ASP.NET site ( by that i mean no fancy jQuery, unless it is very basic and will not interfere with ASP.NET built-in validation)

thanks!!!

Comment: DO you want it to be disabled always after first click?

Comment: @Samiksha, i need to disable after form submits because if i disable after first click it is disabled once i click to validate data with ASP.NET validation.

Comment: I have update my answer, please check now. what you need to do, before disable button, you need to check Page_ClientValidate()

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do this on the button in client side:

```
onClientClick="this.disabled=true;"
```

You can also use the approach from Muhammad with this:

```
onClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()){this.disabled=true;}"
```

If this is still not working, you can initiate the postback yourself before disabling the button:

```
onClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()){__doPostBack;this.disabled=true;}"
```

Comment: @Oded, doesn't work in Chrome after ASP.NET Validation been made.

Comment: @eugeneK - "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. What doesn't work?

Comment: @Oded, the Button doesn't click after validation

Comment: @eugeneK - and other browswers?

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair - where did you see that this is xhtml?

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair - I will rephrase. What in the question makes you think it has anything to do with XHtml? How do you know this is not simply html 4 or 5?

Comment: @Oded: with html4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1. so anyway, not really correct. i fear this causes chrome to not accept it ... :(

Comment: @Oded and @Andreas Niedermair, do you understand what fails? If Button is disabled on client and there are ASP:Validators it fails.

Comment: @Oded, it still doesn't work with even with Muhammad's fix for Client Validation.

Don't know what the problem. button just becomes unclickable after few failed validations once i set proper login details

Comment: @eugeneK - you can try to postback before disabling the button. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Oded, still fails even with your 3rd solution.

Comment: @eugeneK - still the same, or any different? All browsers or only chrome?

Comment: @Oded, i do my tests in Chrome only. I don't know about other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Create a static method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Disable the button on submit. Remember to set up the validationGroup property if there is more than one form/submit
/// </summary>
/// <param name="objButton">The submit button object</param>
public static void disableSubmitButton(Button objButton)
{
    objButton.CausesValidation = false;
    string validationGroup = objButton.ValidationGroup;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationGroup))
        objButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (Page_ClientValidate()) {this.value=\"Processing...\";this.disabled=true;" + objButton.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(objButton, "").ToString() + "}");
    else
        objButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if (Page_ClientValidate(\"" + validationGroup + "\")) {this.value=\"Processing...\";this.disabled=true;" + objButton.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(objButton, "").ToString() + "}");
}
```

Create a form and put a button in your form (Remember to set up the validationGroup property if there is more than one form/submit):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Call it in page load:

```
CommonFunctions.disableSubmitButton(btnSubmit);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()){__doPostBack;this.disabled=true;}" 
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but all the answers fail in some circumstances. Mainly you risk getting a "Page_ClientValidate is not defined" error in the browser.

This approach does work:

```
public static void DisableSubmitButton(Button button)
{
    button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + button.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(button, String.Empty));
}
```

Comment: None of the other answers worked in my situation, but this worked no problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might go for [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).
it's really nice, as it blocks the complete ui, not only the button - so that a user can't click on another button (eg. you want to save ... takes some time ... user clicks on delete meanwhile)

Comment: Problem with that approach is. There are two things ASP:Button does.
1.JS validation using ASP.NET Validators.
2.Triggering OnClick=""

this script can be executed on client, thus will fail JS validation.

Comment: 1. i do not think, that this would be a problem. you can redifine the client-validation-function and execute the blocking after validation is ok. 2. how for god's sake can you trigger a server-event on client-side?? summary: you should give more information and some code (code-behind & markup & final html).

Comment: by the way - there's another approach: why not redifine the submit-handler of the form. if the form gets submitted by the last instance (eg your client-validation) you can block the ui, can't you?

Comment: i'm not familiar with ClientValidation methods which are triggered once validated

Comment: then i would suggest, to implement your own eventHandler for form-submit. this would occure if any button is clicked and any validiation succeeded.